# Using the selection index in looped d3.js transition

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js

Using transitions in d3.js I'm trying to update a property of a selection using the index of the elements in it (i.e. `(d, i) => (t => f(i, t)`). The first run through the animation works fine, but when the loop is run for the second time, the index `i` that gets passed into my transition function defaults to 0 for each element, and so each element starts to behave in the same way. I've included a minimal demonstration (note that while there is a better way to do it for this praticular problem, that is not the case for the actual problem I'm working on).

Un-commenting `console.log(i)` where I've commented it out confirms the issue.

I feel like there's something about the inner workings of d3.js I'm missing here. My (vague) interpretation is that things go off the rails the second time `d3.active(this)` is called, causing the selection to somehow be broken up into its constituents.

```js
            
let svg = d3.select("svg")
              .attr("width", 700)
            
let pts = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50]

let rects = svg.append("g")
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(pts)
  .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", d => d*12)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr("height", 100)
    .attr("opacity", (d, i) => i/10)

rects.transition()
  .duration(3000)
  .ease(d3.easeLinear)
  .on("start", function repeat() {
    d3.active(this)
      .attrTween("opacity", (d, i) => {
        return function(t) {
          //console.log(i)
          return i/10 + t
        }
    })
      .transition()
      .duration(3000)
      .ease(d3.easeLinear)
      .attrTween("opacity", (d, i) => {
        return function(t) {
          return 1 - t * (1 - i/10)
        }
    })
      .transition()
      .on("start", repeat)
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Having different initial opacities, use a function that transit a non-zero opacity to zero in a time interval depending on the initial opacity, and then transits it back to 1 with a constant timeout:

```
const transitOpacity = el => {
      const opacity = parseFloat(el.attr('opacity'));
      let delay, target;
      if (opacity > 0) {
        delay = 3000 * opacity;
        target = 0;
      }
      else {
        delay = 3000;
        target = 1;
      }
      el.transition().duration(delay).attr('opacity', target);
      setTimeout(() => transitOpacity(el), delay);
    }
```

See it's working in the snippet:

```js
let svg = d3.select("svg").attr("width", 700)
            

let pts = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50]

const transitOpacity = el => {
  const opacity = parseFloat(el.attr('opacity'));
  let delay, target;
  if (opacity > 0) {
    delay = 3000 * opacity;
    target = 0;
  }
  else {
    delay = 3000;
    target = 1;
  }
  el.transition().duration(delay).attr('opacity', target);
  setTimeout(() => transitOpacity(el), delay);
}

let rects = svg.append("g")
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(pts)
  .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", d => d*12)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr("height", 100)
    .attr("opacity", (d, i) => i / pts.length)
    .each(function() {
      const el = d3.select(this);
      transitOpacity(el);
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg />
```